# Sample TFS 2010 Build Process Template for NCover

Tags: tfs, nunit, tfsbuild, ncover, tfs-2010

I have successfully integrated NUnit with TFS 2010 team build. I want to now run the code coverage for the build using NCover.

Can you please provide me the sample build process template for TFS 2010 which I can use?

Comment: Check if this answer is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/6878742/728929